# How to create a special kind of list?

Tags: haskell

I have to create a special kind of list in Haskell. First I had to create a function whether it's an abundant number or not. 
An abundant number is when summing the divisors of number the result is bigger then the double of the original number, for example in the case of

```
12-> 1,2,3,4,6,12 > 24
```

I had this solution:

```
 abundant n =  sum[x | x <- [1..(n-1)], n `rem` x == 0]+n> 2*n
```

Now I should create a list which shows you a certain number of abundant number, how should I do it?

Comment: Hint: use `filter` https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter and `take`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:take

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same answer but in the notation of list-comprehension:

```
[x | x <- [1..], abundant x]
```

Example:

```
take 10 ([x | x <- [1..], abundant x])
```

> Out: [12,18,20,24,30,36,40,42,48,54]

As requested from comments, here's it all in one function:

```
abundantnr i = take i ([x | x <- [1..], abundant x])
                 where abundant n = sum[x | x <- [1..(n-1)], n `rem` x == 0]+n> 2*n
```

Usage:

```
abundantnr 10
```

> Out: [12,18,20,24,30,36,40,42,48,54]

Comment: and how should I do it if it must be written just in one line? the automathic tester doesn't execpts this version...

Comment: In line with what you tried on luqui's solution, you could make a function:
`abundantnr i = take i ([x | x <- [1..], abundant x])`

Comment: yeah I got it, these solutions work perfectly, but I mean one line, like everything in a single line, it even should work if I copy paste it in to a new interpreter without any history

Comment: Then pass your `abundant n` function as a `where`-clause.

Comment: I've updated the answer with it all in one function. If you need it on one line specifically, and not one function, then follow with the where-clause immediately without doing a line-break.

Comment: BTW parens are unnecessary in this case: `take 10 [x | ...]`

Answer (score 3):

I like to encourage people to think through things but there isn't much to this one.

```
filter abundant [1..]
```

This gives you an infinite list of abundant numbers.  You can [`take`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:take) from it to get a finite list.

Comment: with the filter abundant [1..] I could make an infinite list, but somehow the take doesn"t work.
abundantnr i = take i[filter abundant [1..]]

Comment: Bracket-parens are for lists and list-comprehension. You want to do `abundantnr i = take i (filter abundant [1..])`